# CloudPagesURL Error Message

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, marketing-cloud-connect, cloudpage

In Marketing Cloud I'm trying to send customers entering a campaign in Salesforce an opt-in email through Journey Builder, using Salesforce Data as the entry source.
The opt-in email asks the customer to confirm their opt-in by clicking a button that links to 'registration successful' webpage via a CloudPage.

I'm using this AMPscript in the email (DOI is Double Opt-in):

```
%%[VAR @campaignID, @email, @firstname, @lastname, @subscriberkey, @leadID, @ContactId, @DOI
SET @campaignID = '7013Y000001giT2QAI'
SET @email = email
SET @firstname = FirstName
SET @lastname = LastName
SET @subscriberkey = SubscriberKey
SET @leadID = LeadId
SET @ContactId = ContactId
SET @DOI = 'True'
]%%
```

And this AMPscript for the URL link:

```
%%=CloudPagesURL(2441,leadID, @leadID, ContactId, @ContactId, campaignID, @campaignID, email ,@email, firstname , @firstname, lastname ,  @lastname )=%%
```

I get this error message when trying to Preview and Test

'The subscriber preview failed to generate. Review the details, correct all issues, and try again.
An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a InvokeCloudPagesURL function call. See inner exception for details. An item with the same key has already been added.'

This setup works from other Data Extensions but not from the Data Extension created by Journey Builder.  The only difference I can see is that the Data Extension created by Journey builder doesn't have a Subscriber Key field.

Advice most welcome.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this same problem. In my case it's because the apostrophe's were not the correct character. I had copied the string from a quip doc and so I had to retype the apostrophe. Once I did, this worked fine.

`%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(5122,'emailAddr',emailaddr,'_subscriberkey',_subscriberkey,'subscriberid',subscriberid,'jobid',jobid,'MemberID',MemberID,'listid',listid,'_JobSubscriberBatchID',_JobSubscriberBatchID,'joburlid',joburlid))=%%`